# ReactJS.Net gives error hydrate is not a function when clientOnly = true on Html.React()

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs.net

After upgrading Nuget package for React.Core to v3.3.0 I get the error -
ReactDOM.hydrate is not a function.

`@Html.React("DummyComponent", props, clientOnly: true)
@Html.ReactInitJavascript()`

serverOnly: true does not have any problem with ReactDOM.hydrate but when I pass clientOnly:true it throws error. I tried searching for this issue, couldn't find any that can help.

Comment: Two years later and the problem still exists  (I'm using the nuget package React.Core 5.2.8)